# Cupy DLL load failed

Tags: pytorch, cupy

I am trying to use cupy to speed up some background numpy operations in my python code but when attempting to import cupy I am told that the DLL load failed, importError: DLL load failed.

I am fairly inexperienced when it comes to handling things like this so any help would be greatly appreciated. The entire error message and trace is copied below:

when I tried pip install cupy-cuda112, cupy import is working but pytorch import is not working.

```
Error loading "C:\Users\CT1\miniconda3\envs\DentiumRIP\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\cublas64_11.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

And, when I do conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.2 -c pytorch -c conda-forge, the cupy import doesn't work.

please tell me how to fix it..

```
Failed to import CuPy.

If you installed CuPy via wheels (cupy-cudaXXX or cupy-rocm-X-X), make sure that the package matches with the version of CUDA or ROCm installed.

On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm.
On Windows, try setting CUDA_PATH environment variable.

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

Original error:
  ImportError: DLL load failed: 지정된 프로시저를 찾을 수 없습니다.
```